# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO Fails to start DFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have installed/configured Hadoop on windows hadoop-2.6.0

I couldn't successfully start "sbin\start-dfs" run command.

I am getting below error

```
16/12/20 13:03:56 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.a
ccess0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)

        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:5
57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canWrite(FileUtil.java:996)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyze
Storage(Storage.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSI
mage.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(
FSImage.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNam
esystem.java:1020)
```

There was a similar question for running YARN. And it was told that including hadoop-2.6.0/sbin and hadoop-2.6.0/bin in path would resolve the problem. But still i am facing the error.

Can anyone help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have proper access permission to namenode directory. Also, format the namenode and start the hdfs services.